# Apache Flink + java 17 + spring boot 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I upgrade my spring boot and java version and run my apache flink application but it is giving me error like

> Unable to make field private static final int
> java.lang.Class.ANNOTATION accessible: module java.base does not
> "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @679b62af

I am new to flink I am able to run the application with above mentioned error means spring application able to run tomcat server but it is not able to run flink as it is giving me above mentioned error

I googled to know that does apache flink supports java version 17 or not and i am looking for the solution which shows how apache flink works with java 17 with spring boot parent version 3.1.0

Here I am also sharing pom.xml

> 

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.digipay</groupId>
<artifactId>fraud_detection</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>fraud_detection</name>
<description>Fraud Detection Docker</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>



<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                <argLine>--illegal-access=warn</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java`? Can you show your pom.xml/build.gradle as well as the whole stack trace?

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike i added pom.xml in my question you can check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no released Flink version yet that support Java 17. The upcoming Flink 1.18 will be the first version that supports Java 17, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15736

Answer (score 1):

Currently flink support only java 8 and 11,There is no released Flink version yet that support Java 17 and above.